# Text alignment with html-css

Tags: html, css

I am styling a website according to the design I laid out. But my text are starting from the extreme right. I want to be somewhat in the middle with no much spacing after the text. Using `margin-inline-start` and `margin-inline-end` does not seem to do the trick.

What I have now:

[image]

What I want to achieve:

[image]

The HTML css style:

```
p .welcome-text1 .welcome-text2 {
    font-family: 'Montserrat';
    font-size: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-inline-start: 40px;
    margin-inline-end: 40px;
}
```

Comment: Can you also put how the tittles are in your html ?

Comment: What do you mean please?

Comment: If you can show the elements that you have with the .welcome-text classes in your html to have more clear the structure you are using

Comment: Please post all of your html and css not just the above snippet.

Comment: One moment! Posting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go, let me know if you need any adjustments made. Only change you should have to do is add in your border.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <style>
        p .welcome-text1 .welcome-text2 {
            font-family: 'Montserrat';
            font-size: 10px;
            text-align: center;
            font-weight: bold;
            margin-inline-start: 40px;
            margin-inline-end: 40px;
        }
       
        .your-bg {
         background-color: #3e4fa2;
        }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body class="your-bg">
      <div class="container text-center text-white">
        <h1>Welcome To The Data Science</h1>
        <h1>And Machine Learning Platform</h1>
        <hr class="bg-white">
        <h3>
            That provides the tools that allow you to explore your data seemlessly and get insights into your data and allows
            you to easily apply Machine learning to make predictions with your data.
        </h3>
      </div>
    
    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use container class of Bootstrap
First get the CDN copied from the bootstrap's website and add it in your html file before the head tag.
Now put all of your contents in the 'container' class using:

```
<div class='container'>
    your content
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try add this:

```
p .welcome-text1 .welcome-text2 {
    display: block;
    margin: 0% 10%;
}
```

You  can change the second parameter in margin. that's the margin from left and right side. First is top and bottom.

Hope, that's help!